# Prevent mouse interaction with transparent element background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a base html element and I have an overlay element that contains some buttons.

I want the mouse to be able to interact both with the base element as well as with the buttons in the overlay.

The problem is that the overlay captures the mouse events of the base element.

Is there a way that I can disable the mouse interactions for the transparent background of the overlay (like IE seems to do), while keeping the mouse interactions for the buttons inside the overlay ? Or do I need to change the structure of my code ?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XC95u/2/)

Comment: That does not work, it completely disables the overlay, including the buttons. I would need a way to prevent the transparent background of the overlay from capturing mouse events, not the entire overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.

With an overlay element:
http://jsfiddle.net/XC95u/11/

Without an overlay element:
http://jsfiddle.net/XC95u/3/

Comment: My jsFiddle example is greatly simplified from my actual code and creating a workaround would be more complex than for the simplified example. I am mostly interested in if it is possible or not to make the transparent background either to ignore the mouse events (like IE seems to do) or to propagate them further. Beyond that, I will have to change the structure of the code.

Comment: You could use elementFromPoint and hide() for a more complex base div with multiple elements inside of it - http://jsfiddle.net/XC95u/18/

Answer (score 0):

I modified the html structure and use z-index to control the positions of the divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
    <div class="button left"></div>
    <div class="button right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS：

```
.main {
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.base {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.button {
    background-color: #707070;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;

    z-index: 99;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
}​
```

Comment: I am afraid that my jsFiddle example is greatly simplified from my actual code and creating a workaround would be more complex than for the simplified example. I know how to create a workaround but at this time I am mostly interested in if it is possible or not to make the transparent background either to ignore the mouse events (like IE seems to do) or to propagate them further. Beyond that, I will have to change the structure of the code.